# Can someone explain the result of this query to me?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT 'Equal'
WHERE ' ' = ''
```

Result:

```
-----
Equal

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: What are you having trouble figuring out?

Comment: string comparison is affected by a lot of things, including language. maybe your locale settings are not what you expect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SQL Server does not consider trailing spaces when comparing strings using the = operator.  That's why it considers ' ' to be equivalent to ''.

Here's a page that explains the semantics:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316626

Comment: They don't seem to count in the `LEN` function either. Seems like an odd decision to make.

Comment: @Phil I think I can understand why the `LEN` function is implemented that way. Imagine that you're using it on a char(5) field. Since it's fixed length, if you considered trailing spaces, then `LEN` would always return 5 for that field, which isn't very useful. I imagine that 99% of the time you wouldn't/shouldn't care about trailing whitespace. I think that if code is depending on trailing spaces stored in the database, then I would really question why that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server evaluated `' ' = ''` as a boolean type that equated to TRUE, therefore it will return the string literal that you specified in your SELECT.

The same would occur with: SELECT 'Equal' WHERE 1=1

Comment: Right, but why does `' ' = ''`?

Comment: Exactly, I could understand if the left and right sides of the equality were the same.